# Separate AJAX controller vs current controller?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, coding-style, codeigniter-3, code-structure

I have a question more regarding style and organization that anything else. I often find myself having a single page (controller) that requires multiple ajax calls. Rather than creating a separate controller just for the AJAX calls because that would mean more controllers I just do the following:

```
class Management extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->protect->protect();
        if ($this->uri->segment(2, 0) !== 0 && !$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('management_model');
        $data['row_config'] = $this->management_model->getConfigRows();
        $data['row_users'] = $this->management_model->getUsers();
        $data['roles'] = $this->management_model->getRoles();
        $this->tpl->head();
        $this->load->view('management/scripts');
        $this->tpl->body();
        if ($this->messages->hasMessages()) {
            $this->output->append_output($this->messages->display());
        }
        $this->load->view('management/manage', $data);
        $this->load->view('management/current_users', $data);
        $this->load->view('management/modals', $data);
        $this->tpl->footer();
    }

    public function get_user_details()
    {
        $user = new \Auth\ASUser($_POST['userId']);
        echo json_encode($user->getAll());
    }

    public function delete_user()
    {
        $user = new \Auth\ASUser($_POST['userId']);
        $user->deleteUser(true);
    }
```

As the index is the only page where I actually need to render a proper view, and the rest are ajax calls I just check the URI segment to see if something other than the index exists and then check if its an ajax request.

Is this bad practice? Should I separate the AJAX calls and the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is asking an opinion which is contrary to Stack Overflow's SOP. But I'll offer my opinion anyway.

Is this **bad** practice? I don't think so. That said, why make a controller larger than it needs to be? If your Ajax is handling the full CRUD functionality for some page then the controller could be quite large. You might be better served by a separate controller.

An Ajax call is a distinct request to the server - essentially the same as directing the browser to a separate page on some other browser tab. Why not make that request to a controller that is dedicated to Ajax? It could be argued that such a controller produces better "Separation of Concerns". That is good practice.

There is one technique to make certain this controller is only used when requested by an ajax call. A couple lines of code in the controller will make the determination.

```
class Some_ajax_handler extends CI_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      if(!is_ajax()){
          show_404();
      }  
      parent :: __construct();
      //if needed, do the rest of your construct here
  }

  public function get_user_details()
  {
     $user = new \Auth\ASUser($_POST['userId']);
     echo json_encode($user->getAll());
  }
}
```

The call to `show_404();` ends with a call to `exit()` so you don't need a `return;` statement or `else` block in the controller. You can be confident that any method that gets called on this controller is indeed an ajax request.

On the other hand, if a controller's view uses Ajax to get the contents for a select input, or some other simple GET call, then creating a separate controller seems like overkill.

BTW, there is a CI library simplifying Ajax calls [HERE](https://github.com/joshcam/Codeigniter-jQuery-Ajax) that you might find interesting.

The one criticism I offer isn't about ajax but about your use of `new` which is contrary to the "Codeigniter way" for loading and utilizing other classes (libraries). But I guess that's a different topic.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, i don't think that there is a pattern on where you should add your ajax functions, especially in Codeigniter which is loosely coupled for most of it's structure.

In my opinion you should ask yourself the below, in order to find where you should place your ajax calls.

1. Are the returned data from the ajax call, related to the Controller i am already?
2. Will i ever use again the same method/functionality in another Controller or somewhere else?
3. Do i need the already defined constructor of the Controller, which i think i should place the ajax call?
4. Do i count on the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of software development?
5. Is my code flexible, reusable, etc.?

Each project has it's own philosophy and workflow. The design pattern and the data structure that you will decide you will follow, will solve most of your questions in your coding-style.